# Compile-time list of enum values

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

In modern C++ (GCC 5.1.0, so C++14, I guess), what is the quickest way to pass, at compile-time, a list of values of an `enum`, and then, at runtime, check which values are in there?

```
enum foobar { foo, bar, baz };

template<????>
void f() {
  if( contains<????, foo>() )
    std::cout << "foo!";
  if( contains<????, bar>() )
    std::cout << "bar!";
  if( contains<????, baz>() )
    std::cout << "baz!";
}

f<foo,bar>();
```

*Note:* This is for unit tests, so speed etc. are mainly irrelevant and the main objective is for it to be decipherable by someone who is not familiar with the code.

Comment: Probably achievable with an `enum class`.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Throw me a bone, you did.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You want to check if a given enum type has a given value name inside it, is that correct?

Comment: @Frank: _"list of values of enums"_ I put a usage example in there.

Comment: @sbi, so, basically a `std::integer_sequence<foobar, foo, bar>`?

Comment: @Frank: Sounds like it might be a fit. Looking it up now.

Comment: The most idiomatic and therefore understandable method would be to give the enumerants power-of-2 values and OR them together as flags....are you unwilling to do that?

Comment: @Sneftel: That would be a good solution. However, I have no control over the enum. (OTOH, it is supposed to be a contiguous series of integers, so I might use them to shift bits to power-of-2... Mhmm.)

Comment: Something like this? https://godbolt.org/g/4AbhHu It's super rough, and a lot more painful than necessary. It would be a lot easier in c++17. I'm sure it can be refined a lot.

Comment: @Frank: Actually, I was looking for something less complex. `:-/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one proposal

```
#include <initializer_list>// pulled in by a lot of stuff

enum class options  { foo,bar,baz };
void test_func(options opt)
{

}
int main()
{
    auto test_vector = { options::foo, options::bar  };
    for (auto option : test_vector)
    {
        test_func(option);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Slightly more complicated to check that the supplied test vectors contain what they should contain:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

enum class options { foo, bar, baz, wuz };
void test_func(options)
{

}

template<typename AT, typename BT>
void assert_test_vectors(AT a, BT check_these_items)
{
    for (auto item : check_these_items)
    {
        auto test = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), item) != a.end();
        if (!test)
        {
            return throw std::runtime_error("You suck");
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
void run_tests(T tests)
{
    const auto better_have_these = { options::foo, options::bar };
    assert_test_vectors(tests, better_have_these);
    for (auto test : tests)
    {
        test_func(test);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const auto test_vectors = { options::foo, options::wuz };
    run_tests(test_vectors);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer because, thanks to a question from Mifhail, it turned out I do not need to pass the enum values at compile time, and in the end this is what I based my solution on.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're still interested but... to answer your original question... if you switch the order of template argument for `contain`... I mean

```
if( contains<foo, ????>() )
```

instead of

```
if( contains<????, foo>() )
```

your `contains` (renamed `containsFB` in my following examples) can be, starting from C++14, a simple `constexpr` function

```
template <foobar F0, foobar ... Fs>
constexpr bool containsFB ()
 {
   using unused = bool[];

   bool ret { false };

   (void)unused { false, ret |= F0 == Fs ... };

   return ret;
 }
```

Starting from C++17 you can also use template folding and `constantFB` can be written as a type traits that inherit from `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`.

```
template <foobar F0, foobar ... Fs>
struct containsFB : public std::integral_constant<bool, ((F0 == Fs) || ...)>
 { };
```

The following is a full working C++14 example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

enum foobar { foo, bar, baz };


template <foobar F0, foobar ... Fs>
constexpr bool containsFB ()
 {
   using unused = bool[];

   bool ret { false };

   (void)unused { false, ret |= F0 == Fs ... };

   return ret;
 }

/* C++17 alternative
template <foobar F0, foobar ... Fs>
struct containsFB : public std::integral_constant<bool, ((F0 == Fs) || ...)>
 { };
 */

template <foobar ... Fs>
void f ()
 {
   if( containsFB<foo, Fs...>() ) std::cout << "foo!";
   if( containsFB<bar, Fs...>() ) std::cout << "bar!";
   if( containsFB<baz, Fs...>() ) std::cout << "baz!";
 }

int main ()
 {
   f<foo,bar>();
 }
```

If you want to make `containsFB` (function or struct) a little more generic, you can templatize the type of the values; so

```
template <typename T, T F0, T ... Fs>
```

instead of

```
template <foobar F0, foobar ... Fs>
```

Answer (score 1):

Variadic option. It prints «foo!bar!baz!foo!», as expected.

```
enum class foobar { foo, bar, baz };

void test() {}

template< typename F, typename... Fs >
void test( F Foo, Fs const&... args )
{
    switch( Foo )
    {
    case foobar::foo:
        std::cout << "foo!";
        break;
    case foobar::bar:
        std::cout << "bar!";
        break;
    case foobar::baz:
        std::cout << "baz!";
        break;
    }
    test( args... );
}

int main() {
    test( foobar::foo, foobar::bar, foobar::baz, foobar::foo );
}
```